# How to Get only Particular value from a grid panel on selected Row

Tags: extjs, ext.net, gridpanel

I have my grid panel as follows

```
<ext:GridPanel ID="GridPanel1" runat="server" Height="300" Title="Title">
    <ColumnModel runat="server">
        <Columns>
        </Columns>
    </ColumnModel>
    <Store>
        <ext:Store ID="Store1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
        </ext:Store>
    </Store>
    <SelectionModel>
        <ext:RowSelectionModel ID="RowSelectionModel1" SingleSelect="true" runat="server">
        </ext:RowSelectionModel>
    </SelectionModel>
    <Buttons>
        <ext:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete">
            <DirectEvents>
                <Click OnEvent="Delete">
                    <ExtraParams>
                        <ext:Parameter Name="Values" Value="Ext.encode(#{GridPanel1}.getRowsValues({selectedOnly:true}))"
                            Mode="Raw" />
                    </ExtraParams>
                </Click>
            </DirectEvents>
        </ext:Button>
    </Buttons>
</ext:GridPanel>
```

This is my grid from my database

[image]

This is my code to delete the selected row but this is looping for row value as i used dictionary

```
protected void Delete(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
{
   string json = e.ExtraParams["Values"];
   string value = string.Empty;
   Dictionary<string, string>[] companies = JSON.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(json);
   bool addHeader = true;

   foreach (Dictionary<string, string> row in companies)
   {
       if (addHeader)
       {
           //sb.Append("<tr>");
           foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in row)
           {
               value = keyValuePair.Value.ToString();
               SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
               con.Open();
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from Users where Name='" + value + "'", con);
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               BindData();
           }
           addHeader = false;
       }
   }
```

}

If I select first row and click on delete I would like to delete that row and Bind grid again. Can any one tell how to do this. Also I would like to alert a message box if the user didn't select any row using Java script

Comment: totally soo wrong method to delet record,try other methods

Answer (score 0):

Is this ExtJs4? Look for getSelectionModel().getSelection() method of your grid control.